# How can I set up my iPad so I don't have to type in my password every time I try to download an app?

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad 4 and I've searched everywhere for the answer to my question. And every website I've been to has given me the exact same answer. I've tried over and over, but it's not working. I've tried resetting my iPad, and I even bought a new iPad recently, and it's doing the same thing. I couldn't figure out how to add an image to my question, so I set my profile pic as a screenshot of my password settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can only remove password authorization for free apps. You can set it so it only asks for it after 15 minutes on paid apps, that is, if you purchased one, it will only ask you for your password if more than 15 minutes have passed when you try to buy a second one.

This restriction does not apply for Apple TV.

Check this Apple Support document for further information: [Manage your iTunes Store and App Store password preferences](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204030)